# How to resolve 'Offline / Missing artifact org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:17-SNAPSHOT' in Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, geotools

I'm new to Maven and am trying to create a simple Maven project given in geotools.org

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- use the latest snapshot -->
    <geotools.version>17-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>
<groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>tutorial</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

The error I am getting is 'Offline / Missing artifact org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:17-SNAPSHOT'. How do I resolve this? I am using Eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1).There is no option for selecting *Project ‣ Update All Maven Dependencies*. In some of the similar questions asked here it was recommended to change the repository URL. Which URL shall I change? Java.net repository OR Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository OR Boundless Maven Repository?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Boundless artifactory](https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/) was down at that moment. For the time being you can use version `16-RC1` as the latest released version, `15.2` as the last stable release.

If you absolutely must be on the cutting edge, I'd recommend downloading/cloning [master](https://github.com/geotools/geotools) and building it locally.

Comment: Using 15.2 as the release version did not solve the error. I used 12.5 and then downloaded the entire geotools jars. Yet, my program is throwing exception

Comment: I can see all releases at https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/geotools/gt-main/ (for example) - try running mvn -U clean install on the CLI

Comment: Where do I run it?

Comment: in the top dir of your project (where the pom.xml file is)

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of ${geotools.version} you should place a real version number of the project, like 15.1
I am not sure though if that's the problem

Also, you might want to consider changing to Gradle build. I think it is a lot simpler